# SuiteCRM : RAM utilization keeps increasing over time

Tags: suitecrm

From last one month my server utilization is increased over time and after 24-30 hours it got crashed .on the daily basis i have to reboot the server.I have 150-200 users for my CRM.

I'm not able to find..where is the issue.If anyone have idea about it,please suggest me how to resolved it.

Below is the required details.

SugarCRM : Version 7.6.5
Sugar Version 6.5.23 (Build 1061)
PHP Version 5.6.28

Apache : Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)
server- 8cpu 32gb ram
100 GB STORAGE
m4.2x large type instance

DataBase : mysql version : 5.7.16-log 2 CPU
, 8GB RAM, 100 GB STORAGE - DB
M4.LARGE

```
*Table* *Size (GB)*

emails_text 16.14

aos_products_quotes 11.35

aop_case_updates    9.15

email_addr_bean_rel 3.37

accounts    2.42

cases   2.16

email_addresses 2.13

contacts    1.91

nm_order    1.7

securitygroups_records  1.43

cases_audit 1.39

emails_email_addr_rel   1.28

emails  1.13

accounts_contacts   1.01

job_queue   0.78

emails_beans    0.72

nm_order_accounts_c 0.71

aod_indexevent  0.61

cases_nm_team_preformance_1_c   0.58

aop_case_events 0.5

nm_team_preformance 0.38

accounts_cstm   0.27

cases_cstm  0.22

tracker 0.19

sugarfeed   0.18

notes   0.11

folders_rel 0.1

contacts_cstm   0.09

cstm_teckinfo   0.09

leads   0.09

leads_cases_1_c 0.08

accounts_audit  0.08

contacts_cases  0.07

contacts_audit  0.07

nm_order_cases_1_c  0.03

cstm_teckinfo_cstm  0.02

user_login_history  0.01

nm_customer_contact 0.01

leads_cstm  0.01

acl_roles_actions   0.01

aos_contracts_audit 0

aos_contracts_documents 0

aos_invoices    0

aos_invoices_audit  0

aos_line_item_groups    0

aos_line_item_groups_audit  0

aos_pdf_templates   0

aos_pdf_templates_audit 0

aos_product_categories  0

aos_product_categories_audit    0

aos_products    0

aos_products_audit  0

templatesectionline_audit   0

aos_products_quotes_audit   0

aos_quotes  0

aos_quotes_aos_invoices_c   0

aos_quotes_audit    0

aos_quotes_os_contracts_c   0

aos_quotes_project_c    0

aow_actions 0

aow_conditions  0

aow_processed   0

aow_processed_aow_actions   0

aow_workflow    0

aow_workflow_audit  0

bugs    0

bugs_audit  0

calls   0

calls_contacts  0

calls_leads 0

calls_reschedule    0

calls_reschedule_audit  0

calls_users 0

campaign_log    0

campaign_trkrs  0

campaigns   0

campaigns_audit 0

templatesectionline 0

tasks   0

cases_bugs  0

securitygroups_users    0

securitygroups_default  0

cases_test  0

config  0

securitygroups_cstm 0

securitygroups_audit    0

contacts_bugs   0

securitygroups_acl_roles    0

securitygroups  0

contacts_users  0

cron_remove_documents   0

schedulers  0

cstm_teckinfo_audit 0

cstm_teckinfo_cases_c   0

saved_search    0

currencies  0

custom_fields   0

document_revisions  0

documents   0

documents_accounts  0

documents_bugs  0

documents_cases 0

documents_contacts  0

documents_opportunities 0

eapm    0

roles_users 0

roles_modules   0

email_cache 0

email_marketing 0

email_marketing_prospect_lists  0

email_templates 0

emailman    0

roles   0

reminders_invitees  0

reminders   0

aos_contracts   0

vcals   0

fields_meta_data    0

folders 0

relationships   0

folders_subscriptions   0

fp_event_locations  0

fp_event_locations_audit    0

fp_event_locations_fp_events_1_c    0

fp_events   0

fp_events_audit 0

fp_events_contacts_c    0

fp_events_fp_event_delegates_1_c    0

fp_events_fp_event_locations_1_c    0

fp_events_leads_1_c 0

fp_events_prospects_1_c 0

import_maps 0

inbound_email   0

inbound_email_autoreply 0

inbound_email_cache_ts  0

jjwg_address_cache  0

jjwg_address_cache_audit    0

jjwg_areas  0

jjwg_areas_audit    0

jjwg_maps   0

jjwg_maps_audit 0

jjwg_maps_jjwg_areas_c  0

jjwg_maps_jjwg_markers_c    0

jjwg_markers    0

jjwg_markers_audit  0

prospects_cstm  0

prospects   0

leads_audit 0

prospect_lists_prospects    0

prospect_lists  0

linked_documents    0

meetings    0

meetings_contacts   0

meetings_cstm   0

meetings_leads  0

meetings_users  0

nm_custom_sms   0

nm_custom_sms_audit 0

prospect_list_campaigns 0

nm_customer_contact_audit   0

nm_default_sms  0

nm_default_sms_audit    0

nm_default_sms_nm_custom_sms_c  0

nm_dispositions 0

nm_dispositions_audit   0

projects_products   0

projects_opportunities  0

nm_order_aos_invoices_1_c   0

nm_order_audit  0

projects_contacts   0

nm_order_documents_c    0

nm_sms_history  0

nm_sms_history_audit    0

projects_cases  0

nm_team_preformance_audit   0

projects_bugs   0

oauth_consumer  0

oauth_nonce 0

oauth_tokens    0

opportunities   0

opportunities_audit 0

opportunities_contacts  0

opportunities_cstm  0

outbound_email  0

outbound_email_audit    0

project 0

project_contacts_1_c    0

project_cstm    0

project_task    0

project_task_audit  0

project_users_1_c   0

projects_accounts   0

aor_scheduled_reports   0

aor_reports_audit   0

aor_fields  0

aor_reports 0

aor_charts  0

aor_conditions  0

upgrade_history 0

aop_case_updates_audit  0

user_preferences    0

aop_case_events_audit   0

aok_knowledgebase_categories    0

aok_knowledgebase_audit 0

aok_knowledge_base_categories_audit 0

aok_knowledgebase   0

aod_indexevent_audit    0

aok_knowledge_base_categories   0

aod_index_audit 0

users   0

am_tasktemplates_audit  0

aod_index   0

am_tasktemplates    0

am_tasktemplates_am_projecttemplates_c  0

am_projecttemplates_audit   0

am_projecttemplates_project_1_c 0

alerts  0

am_projecttemplates 0

acl_roles_users 0

address_book    0

acl_roles   0

users_feeds 0

accounts_opportunities  0

acl_actions 0

users_last_import   0

accounts_cstm_teckinfo_1_c  0

accounts_cases  0

users_password_link 0

users_signatures    0

accounts_bugs   0

releases    0

favorites   0
```

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RgwU.png)

Comment: In htop press Shift + M to sort by memory usage.

Comment: Also Shift + H will toggle thread/process display.

Comment: Hi Jay ,

Thank's for your response.
Max memory usage is 500-600 M for each httpd process,may be because of large data it will create a problem.you have any idea about it.I have 63 GB of data .

Answer (score 0):

How much data you have should usually not matter, as Sugar usually only handles a limited amount of data at a time.
Even if a user would e.g. request ALL quote products at once (by using "Select All"), Sugar limits of how many records will be served in a single request (to about 1000). As far as I know, anyway.

So unless this is some weird Sugar Bug I'd suspect one of these to be the cause:

- You added Logic Hooks or other code to Sugar that either fetches *all* records of a module or does something like `$bean->load_relationship($relName)` and `$bean->$relName->getBeans()` on a record with an immense number of links. You probably don't really *need* to do that, even if you're checking something - instead you could try to filter them on the DB-side (e.g. using SugarQuery or $db->query() with raw SQL or by using filter API internally). Then Sugar/httpd would only have to load those records as Beans that you actually need (if any at all).
- You added Logic Hooks or other code that allocates a lot of objects but doesn't use `unset()` to help the (sadly weak) PHP garbage collector to free memory. Note: Before unsetting Beans in Sugar 7 or higher, you probably want to use `BeanFactory::unregister($bean)` to remove them from the Cache first. I'm not sure if older Versions of Sugar use bean caching as well.
- You added Logic Hooks or other code that misbehaves. Like an infinite loop that allocates memory. Usually that would break website behavior though, unless it happens after the response is sent already or if it only affects requests in the background (e.g. Meetings/Calls/Notifications checker)